# How to scrape button class element and collect with puppeteer and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm developing an app that in a certain sense automates the process of checking your order for nike and the data collected is sent back to the user via discord embed.

I have it pretty much done but there's one thing I'm having an issue with. I'm not able to scrape the button class element that nike uses to tag the tracking number. Does anyone have any ideas? I have attached a ss of the elements related and my current code.

````
     await page.click(".nds-btn.css-1cxnzw1.css-xxsqkh.ex41m6f0.primary", { delay: 2000 });

    /*
    await page.waitForSelector(".sc-cendjg-0.u2kmlc-0.eIyaJU.iyTHDa.u2kmlc-0.sc-17uic18-0.u2kmlc-0.ggum8u-1.cFnOmG.ldmkHq-0.iumkEx");
    await page.click(".sc-196beyx-0.iumkEx");
         let trackingInfo = await page.evaluate(() => {
         let trackingTag = document.querySelectorAll(".sc-196beyx-0.iumkEx");
         let tracking = [];
         trackingTag.forEach((tag) => {
             tracking.push(tag.innerText)
         })
         return tracking;
     });
        console.log('Tracking number has been collected!')*/```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzdgS.jpg
````

Comment: You could use the position of the element instead of the class, if the classes are dynamically generated. Get a bounding rect and check that it falls within the desired location. Check all button elements and if not existing yet wait again a period of time, custom timeout type stuff. Could use the relationship of the elements to others too that have a consistent class.

Comment: How would I go about figuring out the position of it?

Comment: I'd use `page.evaluate` and then just `element.getBoundingClientRect` You could use something like `querySelectorAll("button")` convert the node list into an array, and then use the `.find` method of an array to get the desired button based on bounding rect

Comment: Do you have an example or documentation I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I might wait for an element based on the coords instead of the selector, if selector is dynamically generated.

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

const waitForButton = async (page, coords) => {
    let cntr = 0;
    const LIMIT = 10;
    const WAIT_INTERVAL_MS = 500;
    while (cntr++ < LIMIT) {
        const buttonClass = await page.evaluate((coords) => {
            const {xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax} = coords;
            const buttonFittingCoords = [...document.querySelectorAll("button")].find(btn => {
                const { x, y } = btn.getBoundingClientRect();
                return (
                    ( x < xMax ) &&
                    ( x > xMin ) &&
                    ( y < yMax ) &&
                    ( y > yMin )
                )
            });
            return buttonFittingCoords?.className;
        }, coords);
        if (buttonClass) return buttonClass;
        await wait(WAIT_INTERVAL_MS);
    }
    console.log("Could not find button after "+LIMIT+" attempts waiting " + WAIT_INTERVAL_MS);
    return undefined;
};

(async () => {
    /* 
    got your browser and page and whatnot
    */
    const buttonClassName = await waitForButton(page, {
        xMin: 6, 
        xMax: 9, 
        yMin: 4, 
        yMax: 13
    });
    if (!buttonClassName) throw new Error("button couldn't be found!!!");
    const selector = "." + buttonClassName.replace(/ /g, ".");
    await page.click(selector);
})().catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

Comment: Sorry for just now seeing this, for the button since there's multiple button classes in the same page, should just define it with the button id of .sc-196beyx-0.iumkEx?

Comment: if you're scraping and the class is not consistent, I'm suggesting you find it by the position on the page, and get the class name from there. Then transform that classname to a selector for puppeteer to interact with, if you need trusted events.

Comment: Understood, any documentation on that?

Comment: You want documentation on the evaluate method for puppeteer page objects? Or the HTMLElement `.className` property?

Comment: both preferably if you're about to find documentation on it

Comment: yeah, quick google search will give anything youre looking for. [complete puppeteer docs](https://pptr.dev/), [the evaluate method](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate/), [html element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), [bounding rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), and [classname property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)